Name of this particular type of cabinet hinge
I'm trying to find this type of cabinet hinge for my parent's. We have gone to Home Depot, and were not able to find these parts. Apparently i was told this cabinet hinge was outdated and would have to buy it online.
I been searching and having trouble locating this type of cabinet hinge. Technically the cabinet hinge comes with 2 parts, the top and the bottom plate. The bottom plate is the one that cracked, and so my parents are trying to find the replacement part for it. They had 10 hinges cracked in the similar way, and are looking to see if they can get replacement parts for them.
If anyone can help or direct me, I would most appreciate it. Here's the images of the cabinet hinge: https://imgur.com/a/MsNQcxy

imgur is a time waster, edit your questiond and  use the mountains icon to add pictures directly

Euro-style hinge.

aka cup hinge.

10 different hinges cracked, I would be looking for a different design for replacement.

Look through Rockler
I can find anything I need for cabinets or furniture there.
You will need to take some measurements to find what the offset is and know if your cabinet door is full or half overlay or inset.
Even though the new hinge may not look exactly like the old hinge, with adjustments it will work the same.

The new hinges could have more adjustments that will allow them to fit your cabinet more easily. The most critical thing to match is the size of the cup.  Also, it looks like you have 90-degree hinges, if you replace them with 180 degree hinges that fit the cabinet, they may not suffer the same cracking which is probably from pushing them open too roughly.

35mm or 1 3/8"  is almost an industry standard cup size now for hidden hinges.  It is rare to have a different size.
